# Busting out of iframe from source page to display modal on parent (top) page

Tags: jquery, iframe, framebusting

I'm trying to get a modal window to bust out of my iframe onto the top page when a user clicks the image in the iframe, that will display a video on the main (parent) page. I have the following, but not sure how to implement the JavaScript to push a modal window from the iframed page to the top page.

This is the iframe code that will go onto a parent page:

```
<iframe id="rtv-preview-frame" src="syndicateplayer.html" name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to figure out what I need to have on my `syndicateplayer.html` page, in order to push the content of a modal to the top page as a modal window on top. Looking around at some options, it looks like I would need something similar to this on the page that is in the iframe:

```
var $jParent = window.parent.jQuery;
var dlg1 = $jParent('.rtv-video');
dlg1.dialog();
```

I have tried this, but not able to get the div to push out of the iframe on click. Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381920/how-can-i-pass-attribute-value-from-iframe-to-parent-in-javascript, try searching next time

Comment: Take a look at this question. The second answer. You can allow full screen on the iframe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417517/make-iframes-content-overflow-outside-iframe-extents/17418879#17418879

Comment: @DaniëlTulp - I did search, but that didn't come up in my queries.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, the issue isn't with fullscreen, but how to push the div from the iframed content to the parent page.

Comment: @Matt that is not possible because of browser security reasons. An iframe cannot interact with anything outside of it. Your only options are fullscreen with a transparent background or you can try to trigger and event outside of the iframe with a postmessage. If something happens in the iframe send a postmessage to the parent window telling it to trigger an event based on the received post message. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/, and using this to push the modal to the parent from the iframe: [open modal window from iframe into the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284419/open-modal-window-from-iframe-into-the-parent)