# Modal Window and Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, modal-dialog

I have a link to a model window called within an iframe. Two iframes are sitting on top of each otehr. The iframe its called within (the top one) is set to z-index:9; When I click on the modal window button, it appears inside of the iframe. I am trying to figure out how or where to set the z index to make the modal window appear on top of the iframes. Below is my current code:

I can post the css styling for it if that has anything to do with it as well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect        
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);    

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });        

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });            

});
</script>
```

Comment: As long as the modal is inside the iFrame, the modal will appear there as well and no changing of the z-index will fix that. You need to programmatically move the modal out of the iFrame instead, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284419/open-modal-window-from-iframe-into-the-parent

Comment: that's perfect, I'll take a look at that, thank you Miqi